# Blogger post permalink lost when exporting/importing blog

Tags: google, blogger, permalinks, import

Google's Blogger now allows the original publisher to specify a customized permalink for a post on a blog.

Yet, when one exports and imports this blog, the posts must be republished, and the permalinks are lost.

This is annoying, since posts can refer to other posts using their permalink.

1. Is there any work-around to keep permalinks?
2. Is there any way to predict a link from the post title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any way to keep the permalinks.

Yes, you can predict the link from the post title - I was just about to do the research and write up the current rules when they added the custom-permalink feature, so I didn't bother.   But basically, the text portion is geneated from the start of your post title, with a dash () substituted for spaces, and "small words" (eg "the") left out.

However there's a twitch:  even if you delete a post from your blog, that post-title is unique and can never be used again.  So if a new post (or an imported one) would have the same title as a previous post, some digits are added to the end of the link to make it unique.   And I don't think you can predict those digits.